# Using a mask to automatically paint on Unity terrain

Tags: unity, textures, terrain, maps, art

I am working on a map for an open world project. I am currently designing it in Photoshop which then I will try my best to replicate on Unity terrain by hand.

I have looked around and have been wondering if there is any way to use a mask texture to make Unity terrain automatically paint a path 1:1, even if it uses just one texture layer.

This is the map I'm working on in Photoshop.
[image]

And this is how I've tried to replicate it by hand on the Unity terrain. Is there any way to automate this?
[image]

Comment: Why not draw directly on Unity terrain as you are doing, instead of copying it from a separate document? Is having a `Photoshop` document a requirement?

Comment: @Juris Unfortunately it is a requirement according to my employer, yeah